# error: no matching function for call to 'std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

```
typedef struct {
    string strDatabaseName;
    set <string, greater<string> > setDBAccName;
} UserDBAInfo_t;

typedef struct {
    map<int, UserDBAInfo_t > mapUserDBAInfo;
} UserDBInfo_t;

typedef set<string, greater<string> > setNames_t;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    ...
    map<string, UserDBInfo_t > mapHRUserDBInfo;

    UserDBInfo_t structUserDBInfo;
    UserDBAInfo_t structUserDBAInfo;

    structUserDBAInfo.strDatabaseName = strDatabaseName;
    structUserDBAInfo.setDBAccName.insert(strDBAccName);

    structUserDBInfo.mapUserDBAInfo.insert(nDatabaseID, structUserDBAInfo);

    mapHRUserDBInfo.insert(make_pair(strSabun, structUserDBInfo));   <--- compile error here

    ...

}
```

When I compile it, I got error message.

```
main.cpp:2778: error: no matching function for call to 'std::map&lt;int, UserDBAInfo_t, std::less&lt;int>, std::allocator&lt;std::pair&lt;const int, UserDBAInfo_t> > >::insert(int&, UserDBAInfo_t&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:395: note: candidates are: std::pair&lt;typename std::_Rb_tree&lt;_Key, std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map&lt;_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp>&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = UserDBAInfo_t, _Compare = std::less&lt;int>, _Alloc = std::allocator&lt;std::pair&lt;const int, UserDBAInfo_t> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:419: note:                 typename std::_Rb_tree&lt;_Key, std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator std::map&lt;_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(typename std::_Rb_tree&lt;_Key, std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind&lt;std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, const std::pair&lt;const _Key, _Tp>&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = UserDBAInfo_t, _Compare = std::less&lt;int>, _Alloc = std::allocator&lt;std::pair&lt;const int, UserDBAInfo_t> >]
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Did you include header <map>?

Answer (score 2):

The error message, `no matching function for call to 'std::map, std::allocator > >::insert(int&, UserDBAInfo_t&)`, indicates to me that the problem is in the line:

```
structUserDBInfo.mapUserDBAInfo.insert(nDatabaseID, structUserDBAInfo);
```

not the line you mentioned in your question. That should be:

```
structUserDBInfo.mapUserDBAInfo.insert(make_pair(nDatabaseID, structUserDBAInfo));
```

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can also use:

```
structUserDBInfo.mapUserDBAInfo.emplace(nDatabaseID, structUserDBAInfo);
```