# Cannot insert a enum type into a map

Tags: c++, algorithm, enums, insert, stdmap

I am a novice at C++, but I am trying to build a `std::map` that has an `enum` type as value, to avoid fussing with strings.

I have created a minimum example below which does not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map> 
#include <vector>

enum val_list {Foo, Bar}; 

int main()
{
    std::map<int, val_list> val_map;
    std::vector<std::string> dummy_data = {"0","1","3"};
    
    val_map.insert(0,static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])));  
}
```

I get the following compiler error

```
test.cc:17:66: error: no matching function for call to 
  ‘std::map<int, val_list>::insert(int, val_list)’
   17 |  val_map.insert(0,static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])));
```

---

This toy example is similar to my actual program, which gives me a slightly different error with the same structure

```
enum PhysicalNames {unassigned,top_points,
  side_points, bottom_points, top_lines, 
  side_lines, bottom_lines, symetry_line, 
  top_surface,side_surface,bottom_surface};

std::vector<std::string> entity_data;
std::map<int, PhysicalNames> node_map;

node_map.insert(std::stoi(entity_data[0]),group);
```

This gives me the same error but with a reference variable which is weird

```
error: no matching function for call to 
       ‘std::map<int, PhysicalNames>::insert(int, PhysicalNames&)’
  284 |             node_map.insert(std::stoi(entity_data[0]),group);
```

What am I doing wrong, exactly?

Comment: I guess you just want `val_map[0] = static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0]));`. The `insert` function takes a map entry (key+value pair) as its insertion argument.

Comment: Dupe: [error: no matching function for call to 'std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342937/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-stdmap)

Comment: Prefer type safe `enum class` to `enum` (in most cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `std::map::insert` wrong!

The `std::map::insert` expect a `std::map::value_type` (i.e `std::pair<const Key, T>`) as argument there, not the *key* and *value*.
In your first example, this is `std::pair<const int, val_list>`.

From *[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)* overloads (1) and (3):

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( const value_type& value ); (1)
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value );  (3)    (since C++17)
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That means you need extra `{}` there, so that `value_type` be constructed on the go:

```
val_map.insert({ 0, static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])) });
//            ^^^                                                  ^^^
```

Alternatively, mention the `value_type` while passing

```
val_map.insert(std::pair<const int, val_list>{
      0, static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])) 
});
```

or [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) while passing

```
val_map.insert(std::make_pair(
       0, static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])) 
));
```

---

This could have been avoided if you have used  [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). As a plus, the map entry will be constructed in place in the map.

```
val_map.emplace(0, static_cast<val_list>(std::stoi(dummy_data[0])) );
```

---

As a side note, use `enum struct` or `enum class`, which provids type safety over the plane enums. Read more: [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)

Comment: @Jelo thank you for answering my questions so thoroughly... c++ is hard!